# sql local (#) temp tables - reading data from other connections

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, temp-tables

I working with legacy (ancient is more appropriate word) application which use temp tables (#) to pass data between different stored procdures, temp tables are created in batches (not in stored procedures) so visibility of this table is per connection, scenario is as follows:

> create table #temp ...
>   run stored_procedure_1 - this one for instance inserts data into #temp
>   run stored_procedure_2 - this one for instance uses data inserted previously

**Is there a way to read data from #temp using other connection ?**
In anticipation of questions why I need this ? - application code is very difficult, to better understand what is going on in it, I am often attaching profiler and looking at queries which are sent into db, ability to looking what is inside temp tables created by app connection, would be helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No.**

The `#temp` tables are **specifically** only for the current connection that created them.

If you need globally visible temp tables, use the `##temp` notation (with two `#` at the beginning)

Comment: I can't modify app code so using ## is not possible, I am curious if there is some undocumented hack etc.

Comment: Well if you could get to that long generated name that comes with a temp table, maybe that would work/

Comment: @Krzysiek: **no** - there's no undocumented hack. `#temp` tables are **only** available to the session (connection) that created them.

Comment: my collegue found this https://github.com/FilipDeVos/sp_select/downloads, it does exactly what I was looking for